# Use string from MainActivity.java in activity_main.xml

Tags: android

I have a string defined in MainActivity.java:

```
public String counter1 = String.valueOf(e.getCount());
```

I would like to use this string in activity_main.xml as:

```
android:text="@string/counter1"
```

As you can tell I am very new to this so basic steps would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you cannot. The resources you set in your xml layouts must be statically defined in resources files, like.-

```
<string name="counter1">COUNTER VALUE</string>
```

To dynamically define new strings, you must set them programmatically.-

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
textView.setText(counter1);
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do if you could get this to work? If you want to set text dynamically, you can use `setText`:

```
yourTextView.setText(counter1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set something programmatically which you can... you should use

```
txtview.setText(yourString);
```

if you want to set a String in XML then you either set it in the XML like you did

```
  android:text="Exercise Name"
```

or using strings  which then you can use programmatically as well
in strings:

```
   <string name="Delete">Delete</string>
```

in code you can call it with R.string.Delete or getString(R.string.app_name);

of course you can also set from strings in XML with @string...

by the sound of what you are trying to do, you want the TextView to change while program is running so the first option would suit you well

Answer (score 0):

you can not,if you want to acheive this kind of solution:
create string in strings.xml

```
<string name="counter1">value of counter</string>
```

and if you want to set the text of counter dynamically then in you activity:

```
TextView tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
tView.setText(counter1);
```

you should follow this,because all static strings shoul always be defined in strings.xml